# How to assign cookie expiry date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to learn about cookies. But there is a point I can't understand. Hope, you can help me.

I wrote a short code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["Test2"] == null)
            {
                Response.Cookies["Test2"]["Address"] = "Home";
                Response.Cookies["Test2"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);
            }

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cookies["Test2"]["Address"] = "Work";
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly, I want to check if there is a cookie with the name "Test2". It creates a cookie with the name "Test2". Its expiry date is one minute later it has been created.

[image]

Then, I am clicking the button, it passes the if clause and change Address to Work. But when I look at the cookie expiry date is gone.

> Expires:  When the browsing session ends

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uNWPBRF.png]

Why does this expiry date change? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to modify the cookie , that will **create a new cookie**, and since you haven't specified the `ExpiryDate` it will be limited to when the session will end.

[ASP.NET Cookies Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> You cannot directly modify a cookie. Instead, changing a cookie
> consists of creating a new cookie with new values and then sending the
> cookie to the browser to overwrite the old version on the client.

Also:

> If you do not set the cookie's expiration, the cookie is created but
> it is not stored on the user's hard disk. Instead, the cookie is
> maintained as part of the user's session information. When the user
> closes the browser, the cookie is discarded.

So your options are either not to modify the cookie value *(use some other mechanism like DB)*, or specify a different expiry date with each modification.